# What is the exact condition for a "str" descriptor to be present on a pandas Series?

Tags: pandas

In pandas a lot of columns may get a dtype object. However, some columns possess the str method (df["colname"].str is available), whereas other columns with the same type lack it. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3,4]})
df["new"] = np.array(["a","b","de","quasi"],dtype="O")
df["new_numbers"] = np.array([1,4,2,3],dtype="O")

hasattr(df["new"],"str") # True
hasattr(df["new_numbers"],"str") # False
```

So what is the exact condition which needs to be checked in order to ensure that a new column will get a str-descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

It must have at least one `string` element within the column. Take a mixed example:

```
df['mixed'] = [1, 2, 'a', ['b', 'c']]

df['mixed'].str[0]
```

Output:

```
  NaN
  NaN
  a
  b
```

Comment: Ok - thanks for pointing this out. However, the ugly thing about this behavior is that I seem to need to look at the whole data in order to know if it gets a "str". I can't see it from any "overall" properties of the array

Answer (score 0):

The object dtype is used for column with mixed types as described in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html)

> Columns with mixed types are stored with the object dtype. See the [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes) for more.

If you want an object dtype to have the str descriptor you can cast the type object to an string type

```py
df["new_numbers_str"] = np.array([1,4,2,3], dtype="O")
df["new_numbers_str"] = df["new_numbers_str"].astype("str")
hasattr(df["new_numbers_str"],"str") # True
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But one comment/question: casting via astype("str") - what does it exactly achieve. I mean if I look at the dtype it hasn't changed. It is still object.

Comment: They dtype doesn't change as 'O' or 'object' are a mixed type dtype, but casting to "str" forces to all values to be a string (not mixed type anymore), but as pandas doesn't have a string type does why it is still described as an object dtype.